# Встраивание GET-параметров в pdoPage

Tags: modx, php

Доброго времени суток всем! У меня к вам такой вопрос, делаю выборку товаров с помощью pdoPage:

```
[[!pdoPage?
    &element=`msProducts`
    &parents=`[[*id:is=`1`:then=`17`:else=`[[*id]]`]]`
    &limit=`12`
    &includeTVs=`count_flow,height_good,persent_discount,width_good` 
    &tvPrefix=`tv.`
    &showHidden=`1`         
]]
```

Хотелось бы знать, как можно впихнуть в этот чанк в конструкцию pdoPage условия, полученные от гет-параметра. В моем случае есть меню, где идет ценовая фильтрация товаров (от 1000, от 2000 до 3000, от 3000 до 4000 и выше 4000), если выбираем ссылку, к примеру, от 2000 руб до 3000 руб, то GET выглядит так: `?minprice=2000&maxprice=3000`. Как правильно профильтровать в pdoPage?

Допустим, у меня есть сниппет, который сохраняет гет-парамерты минимальные и максимальные значения:

MinPriceSnippet:

```
<?php
   minprice = $_GET["minprice"]; 
   return minprice;
?>
```

MaxPriceSnippet:

```
<?php
   maxprice = $_GET["maxprice"]; 
   return maxprice;
?>
```

Так будет правильно работать? Что надо получить, так это ценовой диапазон товаров от 2000 до 3000 тысяч, к примеру:

```
[[!pdoPage?
    &element=`msProducts`
    &parents=`[[*id:is=`1`:then=`17`:else=`[[*id]]`]]`
    &limit=`12`
    &includeTVs=`count_flow,height_good,persent_discount,width_good` 
    &tvPrefix=`tv.`
    &showHidden=`1`         
    &where=`{"[[+price]]:<[[!MinPriceSnippet?]]"}`
]]
```

Поясню немного: `[[+price]]` — это поле цены товара, MinPriceSnippet и MaxPriceSnippet — сниппеты по возвращению минимального и максимального значений цены из гет-параметров.

Answer (score 2):

Я сделал вот так, и у меня всё работает:

```
[[!get_cat_filters?
    &toPlaceholder=`dop_filters`
]]

[[!pdoPage?
    &where=`{
        "parent":23
        [[!+dop_filters]]
    }`
    &tpl=`category`
    &limit=`10`
    &showLog=`1`
]]
```

сниппет get_cat_filters выглядел примерно так:

```
<?php
$toPlaceholder = $modx->getOption('toPlaceholder', $scriptProperties, '');
$output = '';
if ($_REQUEST['field']) {
    $val = $_REQUEST['field'];
    // тут простенькая но действенная защита
    $val = preg_replace ("/[^a-zA-ZА-Яа-я0-9\s]/ui","",$val);
    $output .= ',"field":"'.$val.'"';
}
if (!empty($toPlaceholder) && !empty($output)) {
    $modx->setPlaceholder($toPlaceholder,$output);
} else {
    return $output;
}
```